# Dados empilhados. Como trabalhar com isso em pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho uma tabela que esta estruturada com dados "empilhados", isto é, todas as informações de um cliente ocupam algumas primeiras linhas. Terminada as informações desse cliente, o proximo cliente ocupa as proximas linhas, e por ai vai. Estou vendo como posso trabalhar isso no pandas. No cabeçalho de cada bloco de dados de determinado cliente, há algumas informações de identificação, incluindo sua ID, que está denominada como Matricula1, Matricula2, Matricula3...MatriculaN. Uma ideia que eu tive foi criar uma coluna, copiar o dado Matricula para ela e repetir o campo matricula até a matricula seguinte. Por exemplo, no caso da imagem abaixo, repetir a Matricula1 até a linha B25. Na linha B26, a matricula muda, passando a ser Matricula2 e, então, repetir esse valor até a Matricula de outro cliente. Como eu posso fazer isso? Grato.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Veja se minha resposta atende.

Answer (score 0):

## Use Groupby

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': ['Alpha', 'Alpha', 'Beta', 'Beta', 'Gama', 'Delta', 
                            'Gama', 'Gama', 'Alpha', 'Delta', 'Delta', 'Alpha'],
        'Rank': [2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2],
        'Ano': [2014,2015,2014,2015,2014,2015,2016,2017,2016,2014,2015,2017],
        'Pontos':[976,689,963,773,845,712,866,999,684,721,794,700]})

print(df)
     Time  Rank   Ano  Pontos
0   Alpha     2  2014     976
1   Alpha     1  2015     689
2    Beta     3  2014     963
3    Beta     2  2015     773
4    Gama     3  2014     845
5   Delta     1  2015     712
6    Gama     4  2016     866
7    Gama     1  2017     999
8   Alpha     2  2016     684
9   Delta     4  2014     721
10  Delta     1  2015     794
11  Alpha     2  2017     700
```

#### Agrupando pela coluna desejada (aceita multiplas):

```
dfg = df.groupby('Time')
```

#### Iterando sobre os grupos:

```
for name, group in dfg:
  print(name, group, sep='\n')
Alpha
     Time  Rank   Ano  Pontos
0   Alpha     2  2014     976
1   Alpha     1  2015     689
8   Alpha     2  2016     684
11  Alpha     2  2017     700
Beta
   Time  Rank   Ano  Pontos
2  Beta     3  2014     963
3  Beta     2  2015     773
Delta
     Time  Rank   Ano  Pontos
5   Delta     1  2015     712
9   Delta     4  2014     721
10  Delta     1  2015     794
Gama
   Time  Rank   Ano  Pontos
4  Gama     3  2014     845
6  Gama     4  2016     866
7  Gama     1  2017     999
```

#### Selecionando um grupo:

```
print (dfg.get_group('Alpha'))
     Time  Rank   Ano  Pontos
0   Alpha     2  2014     976
1   Alpha     1  2015     689
8   Alpha     2  2016     684
11  Alpha     2  2017     700
```

#### Agregações:

```
print('Media dos pontos de cada time',dfg.Pontos.agg(np.mean), sep='\n')
Media dos pontos de cada time
Time
Alpha    762.250000
Beta     868.000000
Delta    742.333333
Gama     903.333333
Name: Pontos, dtype: float64
    
print('Somatória dos pontos de cada time',dfg.Pontos.agg(np.sum), sep='\n')
Somatória dos pontos de cada time
Time
Alpha    3049
Beta     1736
Delta    2227
Gama     2710
Name: Pontos, dtype: int64
```

#### Filtragem:

```
print('Times que estão presentes 4+ vezes no conjunto de dados:',\  
       dfg.filter(lambda n: len(n) >= 4),  sep='\n')
Times que estão presentes 4+ vezes no conjunto de dados:
     Time  Rank   Ano  Pontos
0   Alpha     2  2014     976
1   Alpha     1  2015     689
8   Alpha     2  2016     684
11  Alpha     2  2017     700
```

A imaginação é o limite para o que vc pode fazer com `pd.groupby` :-)

**Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/pandas-groupby-1)**